# HTML to jQuery objects (Кодогенератор)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Есть инструмент перевода верстки в формат создания через jQuery ?
Предположим у нас есть блок

```
<div>
    <pre id="wow">
        <a href="/test">Generate me to jQuery</a>
    </pre>
    <b class="wise"></b>
</div>
```

И чудесным образом данный кусок dom'а нужно сгенерировать в

```
var some_generator_prefix_root = $("<div>");
var some_generator_prefix_pre = $("<pre>").attr("id","wow");
var some_generator_prefix_a = $("<a>").attr("href","/test");
var some_generator_prefix_b = $("<b>").addClass("wise")
some_generator_prefix_root.append(some_generator_prefix_pre.append(some_generator_prefix_a), some_generator_prefix_b);
```

Comment: $('.block').append - функция добавляет в конец .block код

Comment: а если честно не совсем понятен вопрос.

Comment: Добрый день, кажется Вы кажется начали догадываться о необходимости html-шаблонизаторов. Их множество, например http://handlebarsjs.com/ . Шаблон можно скомпилить в строку и засунуть ее прям в $()

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка , я видимо упустил момент что это попросту кодогенератор, даже не шаблонизатор.

Comment: @Abyss, если у вас есть строчка с версткой то просто внутрь $() засунуть. В чем тогда вопрос, я не понял.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка вот проблема в том, что я хочу ворватся в сгенерированный код и проставить нужные мне события. Или можно обойтись меньшим злом и просто искать нужные блоки в $() и выставлять. Я думаю кодогенератор будет лучше в данном моменте, вопрос существует ли такой.

Comment: В какой код? Какие события? Я вообще перестал вас понимать. Обработчики правильно навешивать через addEventListener а не через onclick и аналоги. Разметка отдельно, поведение отдельно.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка я поправил изначальный вопрос.

Comment: Я почти уверен, что уже был абсолютно такой же вопрос

Comment: @Abyss, такого инструмента мне неизвестно. Поясните зачем он вам нужен, это похоже на ху-проблему.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка я думаю ТС настолько упорот, что считает оптимальным увеличить объём JS-кода. Это ускорит загрузку сайта, компиляцию кода браузером... :D

Comment: @Abyss, чтобы вас не пугал термин "ху проблема": http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy

Comment: @SlyDeath, [включая зануду]: в том чтобы увеличить объем именно js кода ничего плого нету. JS очень быстр. И реакт например так делает со своим virtual dom. Узкое место - обращение к DOM. Эт конечно явно не отменяет того что автор хочет чего-то странного

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка вы явно не встречали людей с "реактом мозга" которые фигачат бандлы весом в 100мб и более. При чём самые дорогие операции с DOM это его модификация. А для этого JS и нужен. Потому увеличение объёма JS за ненадобностью добавляет тормозов к работе сайта.

Comment: @SlyDeath, я на реакте пишу =). Понятно что любую идею можно до абсурда довести если не знаешь что происходит. Ну там фотоальбом Гая Фиери в зависимости вставить. К слову Вы - явно не знаете как работает реакт.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка не знаю, но понимаю, что представленные в пример мной люди - олигофрены. Модульность никто не отменял. :) И лучше не говорить им, что размер JS не имеет значения, они ведь поймут это буквально...

Comment: @SlyDeath ладно, мне кажется мы друг друга поняли, жалко что за холивары в комментариях не дают шапки)

Comment: @SlyDeath я ответил вам в комментариях к вашему ответу.

Answer (score 1):

Вы сами можете написать такой кодогенератор на коленке, но только он не несёт никакой пользы и смысла. ОЧЕНЬ плохо писать js-код без надобности. Его количество напрямую влияет на скорость загрузки сайта и на его производительность. Нужны события?

```
var $wow = $('#wow');
$wow.on('click', function(){
    someCode();
});
```

Чем вам не нравится подход, который использует весь мир? Вы, кажется, пытаетесь изобрести data-binding. Тогда откройте для себя, например, [Vuejs](https://vuejs.org).

Comment: Ваш ответ содержит явно ложное утверждение в первом абзаце. Медленно в jquery лапше не "js-код" а обращение к dom и его перестройка. Сам js быстр и мало весит если соблюдать гигиену. В пределах разумного в дополнительном js как таковом ничего плохого нету.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка конкретезируйте

Comment: конкретизировал

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка когда у вас структура будет состоять из сложной сетки саттелитов, а не "хоум пейджа котика", то каждый лишний байт будет на вес золота. Я просто слишком упорот в  плане экономии. У меня крайне медленный интернет на мобиле и некоторые сайты грузятся по 5 минут из-за вот такого отношения к размерам js/css. Так что проблема имеет место быть.

Comment: щас поясню. Вы говорите "молоток - хреновый. Поменьше используйте молотки". Я поясняю что молоток хороший. То что много плотников пьют не отменяет того что молоток хороший. Не надо обижать молоток. Btw vue не сильно быстрее реакта, просто до него в целом не добрались пьяные плотники.

Comment: @SlyDeath спасибо, ваш продукт мне не нужен. Мне нужно побырику запилить в админке фичу, для которой просто надо перекинуть небольшой блок в jquery код и забыли.

Comment: Я не хочу делать макеты в верстке, вешать хайд, клонировать и прочее. Хочу в динамике создавать нужную мне структуру, удобным для меня образом. В данном вопросе производительность и прочее смысла не имеет.